# Get all records through a join with an extra condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

"Neighborhood" belongs to "city". "City" has many "neighborhoods".

How can I select all **neighborhoods** that belong to a particular **city** by the **city's name**? City name is an attribute stored in the city table.

`Neighborhood.joins(:city)` will get me all neighborhoods, using this SQL:

```
SELECT "neighborhoods".* 
FROM "neighborhoods" 
INNER JOIN "cities" 
ON "cities"."id" = "neighborhoods"."city_id"
```

But what is the Rails way to execute a query with this SQL (only difference is the last line)?

```
SELECT "neighborhoods".* 
FROM "neighborhoods" 
INNER JOIN "cities" 
ON "cities"."id" = "neighborhoods"."city_id"
AND "cities"."name" = "New York"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'rails' way of doing this would be to use active record associations so, in your models

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :neighborhoods
  ....
end

class Neighborhood < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  ...
end
```

Then you can call:

```
neighborhoods = City.find_by(name: "New York").neighborhoods
```

Comment: Being British, I had to restrain myself of doing s/Neighborhood/Neighbourhood/

Answer (score 1):

Just apply a where condition using `cities.name`:

```
Neighborhood.joins(:city).where("cities.name = ?", "New York")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Rails model, not exactly sql, but same result could be:

city = City.where(:name => "New York").first
city.neighborhoods

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code-

```
    City.joins(:neighborhoods).select("neighborhoods.*").where("cities.name = 'New York'")
```

Explaination-

```
It will be 'City.joins(:neighbourhoods)' because City has_many neightbours and 'city_id' will work as foreign key for neighbourhood model.
```

select("neighborhoods.*") will select all columns from neighbourhoods table.

where("cities.name = 'New York'") is your  codition to get all records having 'city name' equal to 'New York'.